# Error when using \align from amsmath

Tags: align, amsmath

I am trying to add a block equation to my paper with an equation number 12.  When I try the following in https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, I get an `invalid equation` error.

I am new to LaTeX, so this may be entirely bad form.

```
\begin{align}
L(\theta; y) = \prod\limit_{j=1}^n (\theta_j e^{-\theta_j y_j})^{\delta_j}(e^{-\theta_j y_j})^{1 - \delta_j}
\label{12}
\end{align}
```

The actual equation portion appears to be fine, but I get an error when using `\align` and `label` to number.

Comment: It would be _much_ easier to debug if you made the example a complete small document that generated the error. also why are you using `align` here there is only one line and no alignment points (`&`) ?

Comment: put it into the editor _without_ the `\begin{align}`  and `\end{align}`

Comment: That site assumes you're already in mathmode, so the `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` are unnecessary. Another thing: you can use semantic labels, e.g. `\label{likelihood}`, and refer to them with `\ref{likelihood}`; LaTeX will assign numbers automatically, and so you don't have to manually renumber everything if you add, remove, or rearrange text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  L(\theta ; y) = \prod \limit
```

as the command is `\limits` with an `s` although it would be more normal to use the default setting here so just delete `\limit`.

Note you should not use `align` unless it is a multiple line equation on which you want to align some operators. A one line equation should use `equation`.